# Update page (update-core.php) & Plugins page (plugins.php) revert to homepage

Tags: plugins, updates, network-admin

I am notified in my admin view of my Wordpress site that I have 1 available update for both the site and plugins (in my Network Admin Dashboard there '1' in red circles next to 'Plugins' and 'Updates')...  But when I try to go to both the updates page & Plugins page, the homepage appears?  The URL at that point is http:///wp-admin/network/update-core.php/, and http:///wp-admin/plugins.php/ respectively.

I can therefore never arrive at the true updates page, and cannot update my Wordpress or plugins.  How can I get the updates or Plugins page to appear?

Comment: It is hard to guess what might be wrong with it, since obviously in _normal_ situation it should work. I would try disabling plugins/switching to default theme.

Comment: Same thing happens in default theme, and the same thing happens for the plugins page (about to update question with that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've since found my own solution:  Delete the .htaccess file in the Wordpress root directory.  I've written more details in a [post on my blog](http://cellepo.com/?p=69) at cellepo.com.